# two way binding string separated by commas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my object:

```
const [opportunity, setOpportunity] = useState({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    experience: '',
});
```

I want to store it in the opportunity experience property like a string separated by commas. Like this for example: 'experience_1,experience_2,experience_3'.

But when i type in the input field i want to be able to have space between the words. Like this for example:  experience_1 experience_2 experience_3

this is my code for the input field:

```
        <InputField
        type='text'
        value={opportunity.experience.split(',').join(' ')} // i think i need changes here
        onChange={(e) => setOpportunity({ ...opportunity, experience: e.currentTarget.value.split(" ").filter(x => x !== '').toString() })} // i think this works
        label={"Experiences"}
    />
```

Any Help Guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.filter(x => x !== '')` with `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` and place it before you call the `.split()` method. This will replace multiple spaces with a single space, and prevent the user from entering in more than one space at a time, while letting them change the contents of your `InputField` component. Remember, **.filter()** works on a cloned copy of the string while **.replace()** works on the string itself, which in this case is the event current target value.

Now it should work as intended.

Like so:

```
<InputField
    type="text"
    value={opportunity.experience
      .split(",")
      .map((x) => x.trim()) // Added .trim() to keep consistent spacing...
      .join(" ")} // ...before joining
    onChange={(e) => {
      setOpportunity({
        ...opportunity,
        experience: e.currentTarget.value
          .replace(/\s+/g, " ") // If you try to use .filter() here, it won't work
          .split(" ")
          .toString(),
      });
    }} 
    label={"Experiences"}
  />
```

I've also chained a trim operation on each value from the state property with `.map()` to keep the spacing consistent during presentation, in the event that the state property was initialized with lots of spaces in between each experience value.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can use my solution with @ItsGeorge's answer if you prefer to have an array store the `experience` values. I tested both ways and it worked!

Comment: Thanks i will have that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated example of my previous answer using `useEffect` to update the state based on the input value. This keeps the input value and the state value separate.

[working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-jang-qzl9v7?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [opportunity, setOpportunity] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    experience: []
  });
  const [experienceValue, setExperienceValue] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const experience = experienceValue.split(" ").filter((x) => x !== "");
    setOpportunity({ ...opportunity, experience });
  }, [experienceValue, opportunity]);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setExperienceValue(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={experienceValue} onChange={handleInput} />
      <br />
      {JSON.stringify(opportunity.experience)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Note in case it's not obvious: `{ ...opportunity, experience }` is using "object literal property value shorthand" because the variable is named `experience` so it's the same as  `{ ...opportunity, experience: experience }`

Comment: thanks for the answer. However this line 'value={opportunity.experience.join(' ')}' in the input field still prevents me to have spaces between the words. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @HappyCoconut oops, you're right. I updated the example with `useEffect` and included a working code sandbox.